# c# disable warnings for #region

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I had one region in many classes "Generated code" and I don't want to disable warnings in each class(#pragma warning disable 1591 and #pragma warning enable 1591), is there a way to disable warning for all regions in solution.

Comment: You can't without some external tool to preprocess your source code. That said if it's generated code why you can't add `#pragma warning disable` automatically? BTW you shouldn't use `#pragma warning enable` but `#pragma warning restore` (previous value may be `disabled` because of command line options or other directives).

Comment: Can you control the generated code? Is that generated code in it's own partial class file? Maybe adding a `[GeneratedCode(..)]` attribute helps.

Comment: Thanks for all! I disabled (XML documentation file) in Build and problem is gone.